Book about Islam's narrative about the Jews
I recently heard about a book written by a Rabbi on the subject of Judaism/the Jews in the narrative told by Islam/the Quran. I can't remember the name of the author or the name of the book. Does anyone know what this book may be, and, if so, where I can find it?

There are a few related books on the subject that might also be useful "The Critical Qur'an" by Robert Spencer, "Hagarism. The Making of the Islamic World" by Patricia Crone, "In the Shaddow of the Sword" by Tom Holland.

Another book that might be useful is "The Jews of Islam" by Bernard Lewis. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691160872?ref_=cm_sw_r_ffobk_cp_ud_dp_JE0XG7PNATABCHF5KZRJ
For the record, I haven't read it, but he's a world class historian.

This seems to vague. Are you sure you don't recall any other details?
